# JQuery Div mousein/out/click background position broken

Tags: jquery

**Background Image:**
https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/Images/TextEditor/buttons.png

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/3RVCy/2/

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FontSize').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '-14px 0px' });
    });
    $('#FontSize').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '0px 0px' });
    });
    $('#FontSize').click(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '-28px 0px' });
    });
});
```

I am looking for the simplest way to have a button where when you hover over it shows background-position: -14px, however out it reverts back to -0px and clicking on it will keep it at -28px. Currently on my local version, if you over out/in it works, click works but then if you hover out when the active style is showing (the click event is the active style) it'll revert back again.

Best Regards,

Tim

Comment: You have to add a jQuery lib to get the jsfiddle working.

Comment: May I suggest using addclass/ removeclass functions? That way you can style it cleaner via css. Also you could do the whole thing in .css instead of javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a button to behave like checkbox - I'll implement it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3RVCy/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var state = false; // pressed
    $('#FontSize').mouseover(function () {
        if(!state) {
            $(this).css({ "background-position": '-14px 0px' });
        }
    });
    $('#FontSize').mouseout(function () {
        if(!state) {
            $(this).css({ "background-position": '0px 0px' });
        }
    });
    $('#FontSize').click(function () {
        if(!state) {
            $(this).css({ "background-position": '-28px 0px' });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ "background-position": '-14px 0px' });
        }
        state = !state;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have jQuery included in your jsFiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/Qkwq4/)

[image]

Works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FontSize').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '-14px 0px' });
    });
    $('#FontSize').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '0px 0px' });
    });
    $('#FontSize').click(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '-28px 0px' });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3RVCy/8/)

```
$('#FontSize').click(function () {
        $('#FontSize').unbind('mouseover');
        $('#FontSize').unbind('mouseout');
        $(this).css({ "background-position": '-28px 0px' });
});
```

Comment: I modified your answer as it provided partly what I needed. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RVCy/4/) an updated version of your own.